# error for delete query in MYSQL python

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have written the following query in mysql using python

```
self.sql.get_value("delete from devices where asset_id = '{}'".format(VARIABLE))
```

When I run this I am getting an error:

> Unable to retrieve data : 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Things I have tried:

1. Select query in same format works fine.
2. Checked if VARIABLE is Null, it is not
3. Tried this - delete from devices where asset_id = 'T1234'

Nothing worked. Any ideas on this would be helpful

Comment: Can you try printing the sql statement and run it on mysql workbench and see if it works

Comment: Try `print(repr(self.sql))`. I bet it's `None`.

Comment: Please show enough code so that we can reproduce the issue!

Comment: Formatting the query with string methods is bad. Please don't do it. Better use parameters as in [this example](http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html)

Comment: @min2bro   i tried running sql statement on work bench, it worked fine there

Comment: BaileyParker :  <SqlConnector.Mysql instance at 0x0485D850> got this for print statement

Comment: @user1851202 Now I see, thats a delete statement what value you are expecting to get out of it?

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51277801/edit) and provide the complete traceback (the complete error message).